# How to split a time series Dataset based on a particular value?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

im working on a time series dataset , i have this Date column form (2007-2017) , lets say i want to make my train dataset from 2007 to 2014 and validation dataset to be 2015 and the last to years for my test data set
so the datasets are :
train dataset includes data from years(2007-2008-2009-2010-2011-2012-2013-2014)
validation dataset includes data from year(2015)
test dataset includes data from years(2016-2017)

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('weatherAUS.csv')
df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending = True, inplace = True)

x_train , x_test ,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=.2,random_state=42)
x_train , x_val ,y_train , y_val = train_test_split(x_train,y_train,test_size=.25,random_state=42)
```

So what is the best practice solution in this situation?

even though i tried to sort the dataset based on Date column before splitting it in order at least to split it 60% for training and 20% for validation and 20% for test, as a try to split it by Date but it didnt work and i realised that this is because that  while splitting the data train_test_split()  shuffle the data while the splitting process
but it obviously wont work cause im splitting the data based on its size not the Date column

Comment: If you want to use defined year for train and other for test, you shouldn't split **randomly**, just split by date

Comment: @mozway thats exactly what i want , but how i can do that ?

Comment: `df_train = df[df['Date'].between(2007, 2014)]`, `df_validation = df[df['Date'].eq(2015)]`, and `df_test = df[df['Date'].gt(2015)]`?

Answer (score 0):

As @mozway suggests you can split your dataset using dates (which is probably the best answer):

```
df_train = df[df['Date'].between(2007, 2014)]
df_validation = df[df['Date'].eq(2015)]
df_test = df[df['Date'].gt(2015)]
```

However, do you notice the `shuffle` (default True) parameter of [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)?

```
x_train, x_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2, shuffle=False, random_state=42)
x_train, x_val, y_train , y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=.25, shuffle=False, random_state=42)
```